# Problem in rooting

Tags: adb, root-access, superuser

Two weeks ago I tried to root my android phone using Kingo root app on android but somehow it went wrong and it stopped but it copied the `Superuser.apk` to `system/app` and now I want to delete that file using `adb`. But when I type `rm superuser.apk` It gives the following error :  `rm failed for superuser.apk, Read-only file system` and when I use to mount the file system with read write access with this command : `mount -o remount,rw /system` I get this error :`mount : Readonly file system.` I dont know how to delete `Superuser.apk`, Please help me, thanks

Comment: Are you superuser? You know you can only use `mount` when you have root permission?

Comment: Yes, my phone isn't rooted and it has got superuser.apk! :(

Comment: @GiantTree, please help what should I do???

Comment: You need to properly root and remove that file *or* flash a stock ROM to reset the `/system` partition.

Comment: I couldn't use those one click root apps because as they saw superuser.apk exists they thought my phone was root :(

Comment: If you want to properly root your phone, check xda-developers. Search for your exact phone model and follow the simple step-by-step guides to root your phone (might require you to unlock the bootloader, but I don't have a Huawei to confirm).

Comment: @GiantTree , my phone wasn't listed there :(

Comment: Then it's possibly a device of low interest and there is a reason those one-click apps didn't work. You could ask in the general section of xda whether there is a way to easily root your specific model.

Answer (score 0):

I think your phone has been rooted and the just thing you need to do to remove that **Superuser.apk** is

1. Open adb shell.
2. Type **su**(It will give you superuser access).
3. Then change the file permission (mount the system folder to read and write) and just simply remove that app.

Comment: No bro you just missed it, it isn't root, the rooting process failed at the middle without and recovering and I'm finally giving up root - :(

Comment: @Halo_HeroOfReach As far as I know, the app like **Superuser** or **Busybox** are copied to the phone only after the phone has been rooted. Have you tried typing **su** in adb shell?